# Various Past Tenses in a Single Text

Tags: standard-german

An answer to a question on Quora that I was reading used a variety of past tenses in quick succession. How do the tenses affect the meaning, and how would the meaning change if different tenses were used?

> "Wegen eines erneuten Angriffs seien die alle wieder verschwunden und
>   er habe praktisch alleine zugeschaut, wie sein "Führer" verbrannte.
>   Ich war sprachlos. Wenn er mir eine Gänsehaut hatte verpassen wollen,
>   war ihm das gelungen. Fragen gingen mir durch dem Kopf: Schwindelte er
>   mich an? Er war ein SS-Mann gewesen und schien nicht geläutert."

"seien"

"habe ... zugeschaut"

"war sprachlos"

"hatte verpassen wollen"

"war ... gelungen"

"gingen"

"war ... gewesen"

"schien"

In particular, what are some reasons why does the author used "habe ... zugeschaut" but then "war ... gelungen" and "war ... gewesen"? Is it because the "habe" expresses a conditional? Also, what are some reasons why the author might have used "gingen" and "schien" instead of "hat (hatte) ... gegangen" and "hat (hatte) ... gescheinen"?

Source: Uwe Zimmer's answer to https://de.quora.com/Was-hat-dir-ein-Sterbender-gesagt

Answer (score 8):

This is a story, so **Erzählzeit** is used. That means the main tense is **Präteritum**, and the tense for events before the storyline is **Plusquamperfekt**.

But the introduction is indirect speech, so it uses **Konjunktiv I**.

> Wegen eines erneuten Angriffs seien die alle wieder verschwunden und er habe praktisch alleine zugeschaut, wie sein "Führer" verbrannte.

The next part is the author speaking again.

> Ich war sprachlos. Wenn er mir eine Gänsehaut hatte verpassen wollen, war ihm das gelungen. Fragen gingen mir durch dem Kopf: Schwindelte er mich an? Er war ein SS-Mann gewesen und schien nicht geläutert.

The only clause which is not in *Präteritum* is *Wenn er mir eine Gänsehaut hatte verpassen wollen, …*. – *Wollen* is a modal, and this is indeed *Plusquamperfekt*. You can see it from *hatte*. It's a conditional, but the main clause *… , war ihm das gelungen* indicates the condition was met!

It's a fact → no *Konjunktiv II* !

Comment: What about "war ... gewesen"?